# Flutter 3 - Stop Propagation When Tapping On Widget

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have a `TextField` widget inside a `Container` and want to be able to tap on the `TextField` without the tap propagating to the parent (the Container). I also want to unfocus the `TextField` when tapping outside it. To achieve that I have wrapped the `Container` with an `AbsorbPointer` widget inside a `GestureDetector`. The problem is that this makes all taps go to the Container and I lose the ability to interact with the `TextField`.

How to stop event propagation from the `TextField` to the `Container`?

Edit: Futter docs says that `TextField` widget has a function for tapping outside:

> onTapOutside → TapRegionCallback?
> Called for each tap that occurs outside of the TextFieldTapRegion group when the text field is focused.

This property does not show among the available properties on the `TextField` in my app; `Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable`

Code looks something like this:

```
class Filters extends StatelessWidget {
  const Filters({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
      child: OutlinedButton.icon(
        .
        .
        onPressed: () => {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return Dialog(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => log("parent"),
                    child: AbsorbPointer(
                      child: Container(
                        .
                        .
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            .
                            .
                            TextField(
                              controller: textEditingController,
                              focusNode: focusNode,
                              onTap: () {
                                log("textField..............");
                              },
                              .
                              .
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share your code?

Comment: have you tried using IgnorePointer on the parent Container

Comment: Look into hit behaviours: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/behavior.html

Comment: @MendelG Question is edited now.

Comment: @DanielSogbey That would lead to the container stop absorbing taps which I do not want.

Comment: @MatthewTrent Yes, I did. I have tried to use the Behavior property but it did not work. I might have done it in a wrong way. I would appreciate if you could post an answer based on my code above showing how I could utilize this property to solve my problem!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how to myself. Just read the docs briefly and thought it may help.

Comment: If you remove the gesture detector on the parent container , the gesture detector on the child would work, you can then add a container around the TextField with some padding